# Comment C define with python based on list

Tags: python, c, list

I'm trying to apply a python script to some `C` file in order to comment some defines in it.

My goal is to transform this :

```
#define D_FOO
D_ADD_TEST(foo)
#define D_BAR
D_ADD_TEST(bar)
```

into this :

```
//#define D_FOO
//D_ADD_TEST(foo)
#define D_BAR
D_ADD_TEST(bar)
```

The defines to comment are stored in a list in my python script :

```
> cat myscript.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

var_bar = ['D_FOO']

[Insert the rest of the code here]
```

What could I try?

EDIT:

Combining @sKwa 's answer and some trial and error I got this code :

```
def comment_define(source, destination, tokens):
    with open(source, 'r') as src, open(destination, 'w') as dst:
        for line in src:
            for token in tokens:
                if "#define D_" + token.upper() in line or "#define\tD_" + token.upper() in line:
                    line = '//{}//{}'.format(line, next(src))
            dst.write(line)
```

Which, when ran (`comment_define(foo.c, bar.c, tokens)`) with this output

```
#define D_ITOA
    D_ADD_TEST(itoa);
#define D_STRTRIM
    D_ADD_TEST(strtrim);
#define D_LSTNEW
    D_ADD_TEST(lstnew);
#define D_LSTDELONE
    D_ADD_TEST(lstdelone);
#define D_LSTDEL
    D_ADD_TEST(lstdel);
#define D_LSTADD
    D_ADD_TEST(lstadd);
#define D_LSTITER
    D_ADD_TEST(lstiter);
#define D_LSTMAP
    D_ADD_TEST(lstmap);
```

`tokens = ['lstnew', 'lstdelone', 'lstdel', 'lstadd', 'lstiter', 'lstmap']`

Outputs:

```
//#define   D_LSTNEW
//  D_ADD_TEST(lstnew);
////#define D_LSTDELONE
//  D_ADD_TEST(lstdelone);
//#define   D_LSTDEL
    D_ADD_TEST(lstdel);
//#define   D_LSTADD
//  D_ADD_TEST(lstadd);
//#define   D_LSTITER
//  D_ADD_TEST(lstiter);
//#define D_LSTMAP
//  D_ADD_TEST(lstmap);
```

Why are some commented twice ? And why is one not commented at all ?

Comment: Can people who downvote the question at least say why ? ...


Edit: Changed `it` to `the question`

Comment: I havn't downvoted, but I would gues it's for lack of showing your own effort. You are just presenting a task and are basically asking for code to solve it. You should at least show some effort. You are probably able to open the c file and read it line by line and are stuck with how to identify the relevant lines?

Comment: @juleslasne: Why twice? Because `lstdel` and `lstdelone` in `lstdelone`

Comment: Oh alright that's fair its not important as long as it's commented. The problem I have now is why is one not commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

TKNS=['lstnew', 'lstdelone', 'lstdel', 'lstadd', 'lstiter', 'lstmap']
SRC='test.c'
DST='testbis.c'

def comment_define(source, destination, tokens):
    with open(source, 'r') as src, open(destination, 'w') as dst:
        for line in src:
            for token in tokens:
                if re.match('#define\s+D_%s' % token.upper(), line):
                    line = '//{}//{}'.format(line, next(src))
                    break
            dst.write(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    comment_define(SRC, DST, TKNS)
```

That's based on @sKwa's answer but he deleted it before I could suggest to add a `break` (therefore possibly commenting the same line twice).

I replaced the `in` operator by some regexp match.